# No me imprime números palindrómicos. Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando ver cual es el mayor numero palindrómico multiplicado por 3 dígitos y no se me imprime el resultado.
palindromico significa que se lee igual de las dos formas, tanto de izquierda a derecha como de derecha a izquierda.
El código que estoy utilizando es este:

```
num = 100
num_max = 999
while num <num_max:
    num = num+1
    if num<num_max:
        resultado = num*num


resultado = str(resultado)


if resultado[::-1] == resultado:
    print(resultado)
```

Comment: Pienso que tu código está mal indentado. Las últimas 3 líneas de código podrían ir dentro del `while`, o del `if` (creo que en el `if` queda mejor). Así te imprimirá todos los números que resulten.

Comment: No se entiende el enunciado. Que es eso de un número palindrómico **multiplicado** por tres dígitos? Y tu código en realidad lo que está haciendo es elevar al cuadrado números de tres cifras (aunque por otra parte no hace nada con ninguno de esos números, salvo con el último que es el único que se verifica, por estar la verificación fuera del bucle). Adem´sa te sobra el `if num<num_max`, ya que dentro del bucle `while` siempre se va a cumplir esa condición (pues es la condición del bucle)

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser un problema de indentación. Si lo ajusta así:

```
num = 100
num_max = 999
while num <num_max:
    num = num+1
    if num<num_max:
        resultado = num*num
        resultado = str(resultado)
        if resultado[::-1] == resultado:
            print(resultado)
```

produce:

```
10201
12321
14641
40804
44944
69696
94249
698896
```

Recuerda que en Python es la indentación la que determina que se ejecuta en un `if`, `while` o `for`. Si una línea empieza más a la izquierda del `if`, `while` o `for`, esa línea ya no es parte del comando.

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora lo entiendo